# Other properties in build.properties in SBT

Tags: scala, properties, sbt

It is recommended to write `sbt.version` property into `project/build.properties` file. But i couldn't find any reference about other properties which could be used with this file. Are there any other helpful use cases for `build.properties` file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Prior to sbt 0.9 there used to be more use for this file like [this](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-appengine/blob/097a1d5c3d0d5b6fd282f8122d204a93ef082dd4/project/build.properties), but it's now used only for `sbt.version`. Everything else should go into `build.sbt` or `project/*.scala`.

Comment: Is it required to specify `sbt.version` in `build.properties`? Can it be specified elsewhere? Seems a waste to VC a file just for a single line of text...

Comment: Putting config in `build.sbt` and `*.scala` can be problematic because it can't be read without running `sbt`, which is expensive and attempts to download dependencies in some cases. Is there an alternative standard configuration mechanism that is declarative (not in scala code)?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at sbt's source code, there are a [couple](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/ce3015a2bf36c0386b84fc34585e5a8aeb776338/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Main.scala#L918) of [places](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/450c87f5769e27e0e1bb42b45bd35fe3986a9359/main/src/main/scala/sbt/MainLoop.scala#L91) where the file is read, but only to retrieve the sbt version. It may also be [written](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/ce3015a2bf36c0386b84fc34585e5a8aeb776338/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Main.scala#L1121) back to the file, preserving any other existing content, which means you can use it for other properties, but you'll have to retrieve them yourself, e.g. like [here](https://github.com/darkocerdic/sbt-config/blob/master/project/BuildProperties.scala) (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23149991/843660)).

This may all change of course in future versions of sbt.